# How to subscribe httpRequest and observable in one method in Angular

Tags: angular, database, rxjs, observable

I have to get locations array from database but I don't want to do this every time when user comes in this component. So I want for first calling method get array from database and save. Next to use saved array when user call function again

my service:

```
    locations:Observable<Location[]>;
    isLocationsEmpty = true;
    
    getLocationList() {
    if(this.isLocationsEmpty) {
      this.isLocationsEmpty = false;
      return this.httpClient.get<Location[]>(`${this.apiURL}locations/`, {headers: this.getToken()})
    }
    else return this.locations;
  }
```

my component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getLocationList().subscribe(
      (data:Location[]) => {
        this.locations = data;
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

my error when i call second time:

```
core.js:6241 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at CheckComponent.ngOnInit (check.component.ts:33)
    at callHook (core.js:4726)
    at callHooks (core.js:4690)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4630)
    at refreshView (core.js:12026)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:13404)
    at refreshView (core.js:12035)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13458)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11729)
    at refreshView (core.js:12064)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Service

```
import { of, tap } from 'rxjs';

    locations:Location[] = [] ;
    
    getLocationList():Observable<Location[]>{ {
      if(!this.locations.length) {
        return this.httpClient.get<Location[]>(`${this.apiURL}locations/`, {headers: this.getToken()}).pipe(tap(locations:Location[] => this.locations = locations)
      }
      else return of(this.locations);
  }
```

In your component, you can user your code.

Explanation:

Of, it allows us to return an observable of whatever you want

Tap, it allows us to manipulate the observable data, before return them

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of

Answer (score 0):

To build off the previous answer, it's also a nice feature to use local storage

```
getCache<T = any>(key:string>:T{
  let cachedValue = this.transferState.get(stateKey, null);
  //check local storage and create state value from there
  if(cachedValue === null){
    cachedValue = localStorage.getItem(key)
    this.transferState.set(stateKey, cachedValue);
  }
  return cachedValue;
}
```

Then use it like this

```
values = this.myService.getCache<Array<MyClass>>('myKey');
```

No need to subscribe to it since it isn't an observable